# How can I run SPQuery of Choice field having value '&' (value as 'One & 1')

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In list I have a column 'Issue' which is Choice type having values "One, Two, Three, Four & Five, Six" etc. When I run SPQuery for this column it worked properly except the value 'Four & Five'. Problem is with '&'. It throws error there. When I tried, special character in the column field value, it worked except '&' again.
How can I resolve this, I can take 'and' instead but I want to run with '&'.

Query is:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Issue'/><Value Type='Chioce'>Four & Five</Value></Eq></Where>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using XML in your query you shouldn't use special characters without converting them first.

Try it like this: `'Four &amp; Five'`